# How to architect my android app around a 20 minute http session

Tags: android, multitasking

I have an android app that I'm building and it's based on a web app that lets users login and reserve a book (think library). Because you are able to reserve books it needs to have a valid session (cookie to be exact)

Here is my issue - how can I work with multitasking when I have this 20 minute constraint?

Do I keep a timer running the entire time the app is up (in the Application global object) -then on resume verify this timer is under the 20 min window and if so assume cookie is good - else ask them to login again.

Or do I blow away the activities loaded (in my app) on resume and start the app over each time the user clicks the icon from the home screen

Or something else? I simply avoided this in my iPhone version because I don't support multitasking currently (maybe I will if the android solution fits)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Normally people handle this problem by assuming any cookie they have is valid and letting the server tell them if they need to login again. The client should have very little (read: none, if possible) intelligence about this aspect which they cannot control.

Comment: Yup, handle it behind the scenes. If you get a response that looks like you've timed out, just login again. Keep the user aware that it's not frozen though!

Answer (score 1):

You have several options, and which one's the best will depend on the app specifics

- You can set up a timer to log out after 20 mins, either as part of your Application or as a part of your Activity (although in the latter approach, it will be lost if the activity is restarted).
- Can set an Alarm to fire an Intent to show the login screen after 20 min (if you want to force a re-log in) or to set a flag LOGGED_IN=false if not.
- You can set a long field in your Application object and query it during onDraw(), or while fetching a new page, or whenever you deem fit: if it's past the 20 min point, logout.
- If the app will be fetching the book from a server one page at a time or similar, then I would add a time token to the POST request and let the server decide whether to return the page or to send a 401 error. You would then handle the error by showing the log in screen and reposting if log in is successful